# How would I request that a future version of squashfs incorporate shadowing functions?

Tags: linux, squashfs

Currently you can already append new files to a compressed squashfs, and i thought that would be enough for my usecase, that doesn't actually require replacement because the files are 'last useful versions'.

However, i'd like to add new files. I thought it was fine, but when i tried it, i couldn't add to the same directories as other files, it created a new path similarly named with the first conflicting dir renamed.

I'm wondering if there are plans to lift this restriction for dirs so that support for the appending function can shine like it's meant to; if i'm using it wrong, or if something more radical needs to happen like complete support for file redirection on append.

I'm not interested in knowing about the 'uncompress everything and recompress' workaround, that is obvious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because essentially, you're asking for a new feature in squashfs. While that may or may not happen, stack exchange is hardly the right place to ask about that. Instead, you should talk to the developers of squashfs.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to make a Feature Request on the [squashfs site](https://sourceforge.net/p/squashfs/feature-requests/?source=navbar) though, rather than here.  Or ask in the [discussion forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/squashfs/discussion/215699/) there.